# How can i make autocomplete not delete words after cursor on VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A while ago, VSCode's autocomplete started deleting the word that comes right after the cursor when I autocomplete a word.

Example:

```cs
// I wrote a subtraction and now I want to store the result in a float.
// I use [Home] to put the cursor at the start of the line
// "|" here is the cursor
|Nodes[i, j].Density - Nodes[i + 1, j].Density;

// I write "flo"
flo|Nodes[i, j].Density - Nodes[i + 1, j].Density;

// I press enter to autocomplete flo to float expecting the text to become float|Nodes[i, j]
// so I can press space and type the name of the variable
// but for some reason, now VSCode deletes the "Nodes" and I'm left with:
float|[i, j].Density - Nodes[i + 1, j].Density;
```

**How can i make it not replace the next word?**

I'm not sure what I changed for this to start to happen.
I Changed some settings that seemed related to it (such as Suggest:Insert Mode) but nothing worked.

I'm using VSCode to code in C# for Unity in case that matters.